# No overload matches delegate.. Why?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
Button ssr = new Button();
                ssr.Text = "SSR";
                ssr.Location = new Point(500, 5);
                ssr.Size = new Size(50, 30);
                ssr.Click += new EventHandler(ssr_Click);
```

And I had a method ssr_Click which wrote a "1234" on the button. That was just for testing, now the method looks like this:

```
private void ssr_Click(string callsign, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = "xxxxxxxx";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "callsign=" + callsign;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string squawk = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(squawk); // !!!
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
    }
```

It is okay, it just doesn't know the "callsign", which makes sense, because it is defined somwhere else, so I added "string callsign" to the method parameters that when I call it, I also will give it the callsign. Since I did this, I get an error in first part of code, at line

```
ssr.Click += new EventHandler(ssr_Click);
```

it says this: No overload for 'ssr_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'. It was fine before editing this method.
It is supposed to do this: someone clicks the button, it sends the callsign to the method, gets a four digit code from a .php at website, and it writes the code on the button, so I know that I will also have to edit the method so it returns a string, but first I need to solve this..
Any ideas?

Comment: Your Click event handler must conform to the required signature, you must remove the *callsign* argument.  The framework has no idea how to cough up a value for that argument.  Use a field in your class to store the value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) is a delegate type defined as:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

so your handler method must have the same signature i.e.

```
private void ssr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In your handler, `sender` should be the object which raised the event, so you might be able to get the `callsign` data from that, alternatively you could store it in a member variable.

Comment: Okay, but then how can i get that string into it?

Comment: @MarekBuchtela - Where does it come from at the moment? If it is stored in a UI element you can access it from your handler.

Comment: I have an xml document, I load it and then using foreach I create needed amount of panels, and I put some elements in them (some buttons and labels). One of the labels is "callsign", its a label and a name of the panel created.
 /* callsign */
                Label callsign = new Label();
                callsign.Location = new Point(2, 5);
                callsign.Text = let.Attributes.GetNamedItem("callsign").Value;
                callsign.Size = new Size(105, 18);

this is the code I use to get the callsign, but I cant use it again in this method, because it is different for each panel.

Comment: @MarekBuchtela - If you want the label text, you can locate the label in your handler and use the `Text` property. If you don't want to search the form for the UI element, you should just save the `callsign` label into a member variable after you create it and access it directly in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Remove first argument `string callsign` from event handler method. Event handler for button `Click` event should accept two parameters - sender and event argument.

Remember, that this method should be invoked by button. Button does not know anything about your `callsign` parameter. So, you need to get this value by yourself:

```
private void ssr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string callsign = // get your value e.g. from textbox

     // call to web service
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **[EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx)** delegate needs a method that returns `void` and receives **only two** arguments. First one of type `Object` (which is the sender) and second one of type `EventArgs`. As soon as you added another argument, you changed the function's signature and it is no longer same as the expected delegate.

Solution: Remove the `string callsign` from the method's arguments so it will look like this:

```
private void ssr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```